# How is this type of digraph called?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

Suppose $G=(V,E)$ is a digraph, then we can construct a graph $G'=(V',E')$, where $V'=V$ and $E'$ are defined with the property that $(a,b)\in E'$ iff there exists a path from node $a$ to $b$. What is this type of graph called? What are some of its properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this, you will get a complete (in both directions) digraph on each [strongly connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) (SCC), and then between every pair of SCCs you will either have no edges, or all edges in one direction. If you contract each SCC to a single vertex, you get something that resembles the *condensation* of the digraph, but it won't normally be exactly the same. This is because the condensation includes an edge only where two SCCs are connected by a single edge, whereas your definition puts edges whenever there is a directed path between the SCCs, which may need to go through another SCC. So what you have would be the transitive closure of the condensation; I don't think there is a specific name for that.

Comment: Why a complete digraph? Suppose the edge set $\{(a,b)\}$ then there is a path from a to b, but not from b to a, as you say.

Comment: Then $a$ and $b$ are in different SCCs. You only get a complete digraph on each SCC, and then some more edges between SCCs which correspond to the transitive closure of the condensation.